# Unable to `dotnet restore` while building Docker image connecting to a private Azure DevOps NuGet feed

Tags: .net, docker, dotnet-restore

I have a .NET7 webapi project that is being built as a Docker container.
The project is referencing NuGet package(s) that are published to a private Azure DevOps (on-prem hosted) NuGet feed. Project contains a `NuGet.config` file where this feed is defined and credentials for the feed. Credentials are a Personal Access Token that was generated through Azure DevOps UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />  
    <add key="MyFeed" value="https://.../nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="docker" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PAT_generated_in_devops" />
    </MyFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.203-alpine3.17 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copying all .csproj files here
# ...

COPY ./NuGet.config .

RUN dotnet restore "HttpApi.csproj" -r linux-x64

RUN dotnet publish "HttpApi.csproj" -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore -v:m -o /app -p:PublishReadyToRunComposite=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:EnableCompressionInSingleFile=true

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "HttpApi" ]
```

Executing Dockerfile command that contains
`RUN dotnet restore ProjectName.csproj -r linux-x64` fails with error message: `error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://.../nuget/v3/index.json`

I tried setting up my domain credentials as `packageSourceCredentials` for the NuGet feed.
I tried setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` as docker build arguments. I tried installing a local version of Azure DevOps Express 2022 to eliminate networking issues and connecting to the local NuGet feed. None of these solved the issue.

**EDIT 1:** 
**- NOTE 1:** It's worth noting that dotnet restore works normally when run through Windows PowerShell or through Visual Studio. Issue occurrs when the project is being built by Docker.
**- NOTE 2:** Docker engine is utilizing WSL

Comment: Have you tried to add a "dotnet nuget add source" on the docker file just in case? When building that docker, did you try to use --network=host? I would also try it adding the --privileged flag.

Comment: @FelipeEsteves I am trying to build the image locally, which means the network is the host network. I've tried running `dotnet nuget add source` however it did not work, and the package source is defined in the NuGet.config that is being copied to the build stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I managed to get to work was utilizing artifacts credentials provider as stated here: [Artifacts credentials provider documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider). I also had to explicitly set `-s FEED_URI` argument on the `dotnet restore` command, although the source is also defined in the nuget.config file.

**EDIT 1**
Solution consists of:

1. specify package source in `nuget.config` file located in the solution root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />  
    <add key="MyFeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.ops/Collection/_packaging/feedName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

2. Modify Dockerfile with the following instructions
   a. RUN command that downloads and execute the artifacts credentials provider shell script (Linux) during Docker build to install the nuget plugin
   b. copy `nuget.config` file to build stage
   c. set the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS environment variable (replace `feed_url` with Azure DevOps feed URI and `personal_access_token` with Azure DevOps PAT)
   d. add `-s feed_uri` argument to `dotnet restore` command

```
...

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh

COPY **/*.csproj .
COPY nuget.config .

ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"feed_url\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"personal_access_token\"}]}"

RUN dotnet restore "CustomProject.csproj" -s feed_uri

...
```

Comment: It's a good habit to summarize what you did from the link you post, in case some link expires so that your answer keeps being useful. You may accept your own answer too.

Comment: Thank you @XouDo, I have added the summary for the solution and I will accept my answer once SO allows me to.